# Pulling in data using Entity Framework to Nreco pivotdata

Tags: c#, nreco

I am trying to test out NReco.PivotData for in memory cubing. Our existing process is using entity framework and is able to pull the data but I can't find the right way to put it into the cube.

Tried casting the data as a list, an array, enumerable and json

```
var pvtData = new PivotData(
      new[] { "closeDate", "opportunityName" },
      new SumAggregatorFactory("amount"), true);

  var allRows = (from c in newContext.MCrmOpportunity select c).AsEnumerable();

  pvtData.ProcessData(allRows);
```

The error is on the last line.

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' 
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'

Answer (score 0):

[PivotData.ProcessData method](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PivotData/?topic=html/Overload_NReco_PivotData_PivotData_ProcessData.htm) that accepts only one argument expects either `IEnumerable<DataRow>` or `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, Object>>`. To aggregate data from collection of models you need to use [ProcessData(IEnumerable data, Func getValue)](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PivotData/?topic=html/M_NReco_PivotData_PivotData_ProcessData_3.htm) overload:

```
pvtData.ProcessData(allRows, new ObjectMember().GetValue);
```

(assuming that "closeDate", "opportunityName", "amount" are properties of MCrmOpportunity model)

Note that approach when data is aggregated with "ProcessData" method is good only for small number of models; in case of many database records it is much better to perform aggregation on database level (with SQL GROUP BY) and load aggregation results into PivotData class as described [here](https://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata/load-pre-aggregated-data.aspx).